# Proof that a graph has lebesgue measure zero using fubini's thm

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I want to check if my attempt is valid for a problem.

Q. If  $f : E \rightarrow R$ is L-measurable, prove that the graph of $f$ is a null set in $R^{n+1}$ ($\mu = $ Lebesgue measure)

Note: $E\subset R^n$, is a measurable set, hence $x\in R^n, y \in R, R^{n+1} = R^n 
 \times R $

My Attempt:

By the corollary: $R^n = R^l \times R^m  \ (n = l+m), $ Suppose X is a L-measurable subset of $R^l$ and Y is a L-measurable subset of $R^m$, then the cartesian product $X\times Y$ is an L-measurable subsest of $R^n$

Define the following measurable subsets

$A = \{ (x,y) \in R^{n+1} \ | \ 0 \leq y < f(x), \ x\in E   \}$

$B = \{ (x,y) \in R^{n+1} \ | \ 0 \leq y \leq f(x), \ x\in E   \}$

$C = \{ (x,y) \in R^{n+1} \ | \ -\infty  \leq f(x) < 0, \ x\in E   \}$

$D = \{ (x,y) \in R^{n+1} \ | \ -\infty  \leq f(x) \leq 0, \ x\in E   \}$

Then, letting $G=graph \ of \ f(x) =y $, we observe that

$\mu(G) = \mu(B-A) + \mu(D-C)  $

After taking the x section of each sets A,B,C,D we see that by fubini's thm

$\mu(A) = \mu(B) = \int_{\{x\in E | 0 \leq f(x) \}}^{} f(x) dx$

$\mu(C) = \mu(D) = \int_{\{x\in E | f(x) < 0 \}}^{} f(x) dx$

Hence, $\mu(G) = 0$

Would appreciate any comments or more elegant/simple solutions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G_f$ denote the graph of $f$. If $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^{n}$ and $\nu$ is Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ then  $(\mu \times \nu) (G_f)=\int_{G_f} d\mu \times \nu=0$ by Fubini/Tonelli Theorem because the section of $G_f$ by any point $x \in \mathbb R^{n}$ is the singleton set $\{f(x)\}$ and $\nu \{f(x)\}=0$ for all $x$.